# Python add attribute of property to instance of class

Tags: python

I am trying to redefine attribute for the object with property

```
class MyClass:
    asd = 'asd_string'

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return 1 if self.asd is not None else None


def execute(obj):
    print(obj.bar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MyClass()
    obj.bar = 42
    execute(obj) # 42
    
    obj.bar = property(fget=lambda self: 1 if self.asd is not None else None)
    
    execute(obj) # <property object at 0x7fd058ef7400>
```

I would like to redefine `bar` with something similar to `def foo`
The problem, I cannot edit `MyClass`, and a cannot change the `execute` function
Also, I am not sure that lambda will work with self(instance of `MyClass`)

Is it possible at all to patch the object with options during run time?

Comment: @Asocia Yes, this is useful too, did not find this post before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the new property to `MyClass` instead to the instance

```
prop = property(fget=lambda self: 1 if self.asd is not None else None)
setattr(MyClass, 'bar', prop)
# or
MyClass.bar = prop

execute(obj) # 1
```